# Query Track by ISRC

Tags: api, deezer

Is it possible to get info for a track using the isrc instead of the id?

Instead of

```
http://api.deezer.com/track/123455
```

something like

```
http://api.deezer.com/track/?isrc=8764237
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's not  documented  yet but yes, you can search a track based on it's ISRC number, with the following API call :

```
https://api.deezer.com/2.0/track/isrc:USWB11200587
```

Note that in some cases, your ISRC code may contain a dash between the letters/numbers.